# Use awk to replace a multiple value in a file with the value being processed with a command

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, find

I know the title is little confusing but please bear with me as this is my first post.

Here is my question for you gurus:
I have a file default.yaml where we have password field spread out for a few apps in different blocks like:

- admin_password: xxxxxxx
- web_endpoint: "xxxxxx:9090"
- dbpassword: xxxxxx
- dbusername: dbuser

idea is to use openssl to encrypt decrypt the file for the moment. (I know there are better methods to do it but we are looking for shortcut for now, different reasons)

so when deployment executes i need to decrypt password fields in the file which is checked in as encrypted in svn.

I am newbie for awk and sed and i am trying different ways to do this but not successful. so here is the problem statement:

- File default.yaml contains password field that has encrypted password.
- Find the pattern with "password:"
- replace the encrypted password value after : in that field with the decrypted one after running it through openssl command.
- provide the decrypted file to deployment

i think it is possible to write one line command to do this but please throw in your suggestions as what you can think of it.

so far i have tried this:

```
awk '{if (tolower($1) ~ /password\:/) 
  {''$2=system("openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:mysecretpass" $2)''}; 
  print}' default.yaml
```

i understand that system command will return the status but looking for direction here. thanks a bunch.

I have resolved it with the usage of a temp file but i do not like that solution. Thanks for looking guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below solution -

```
awk 'tolower($1) ~ /password:/ {system( "echo " $1 "openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:mysecretpass" $2 )}' default.yaml
```

hope this help.

Comment: Vipin thanks but that did not work may be i am not clear. Let me clarify more in my question.